# Icon in Unity launcher (14.04)

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

Problem:

Icon for Visual Studio Code is wrong. It uses the icon from the text editor

Things I have tried so far:

I tried setting the Icon with `alacarte` to `/usr/share/code/resources/app/resources/linux/code.png` which exists and is the correct icon. The icon within the menu vanishes, the launcher icon when running is still the text editor icon.

I also completely removed the package and then reinstalled Visual Studio Code with no success

How can I assign the correct icon?

Installation: downloaded deb package and installed it using dpkg --install

Contents of desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Visual Studio Code
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=/usr/bin/code %U
Icon=/usr/share/code/resources/app/resources/linux/code
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
StartupWMClass=/usr/share/code/resources/app/resources/linux/code.png
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;
Actions=new-window;

X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22

Terminal=false

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Name[de]=Neues Fenster
Name[es]=Nueva ventana
Name[fr]=Nouvelle fenêtre
Name[it]=Nuova finestra
Name[ja]=新規ウインドウ
Name[ko]=새 창
Name[ru]=Новое окно
Name[zh_CN]=新建窗口
Name[zh_TW]=開新視窗
Exec=/usr/bin/code --new-window %U
Icon=/usr/share/code/resources/app/resources/linux/code.png
```

Output of `xprop WM_CLASS`

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "code", "Code"
```

PS: I searched this site and have found a lot of similar questions along with answers, but the answers have not helped

PPS: Created a new user as a test, his icon is correct

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: note that Alacarte removes the `.png` extension when editing the icon. (bug) could you post the content of its launcher? (open with `gedit`) and run `xprop WM_CLASS` in a terminal, *then* click on the window of visual studio, post the output as well?

Comment: @Nuwan I used the deb package for x64

Comment: @JacobVlijm I edited the question to include the requested informations

Comment: @JacobVlijm After posting the content I noticed it seems line properties are exchanged. I test and post the result

Comment: @JacobVlijm works now. Thanks for the help Do you want to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### About Alacarte

When you edit the icon of a `.desktop` file with Alacarte, Alacarte copies the global `.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications`, and edits that one. Since on the next login the local one will overrule the global one, to fix your issue, you need to manually edit the local one.

#### Alacarte's bug with icon extensions

Alacarte does not handle icons well however *if they need to have an extension* (like `.png`). This is a known issue; Alacarte simply removes the extension, even if you use the full path to the icon. In your case, Alacarte incorrectly uses:

```
Icon=/usr/share/code/resources/app/resources/linux/code
```

where it should be:

```
Icon=/usr/share/code/resources/app/resources/linux/code.png
```

#### One more issue; incorrect StartupWMClass -line

Also the line:

```
StartupWMClass=/usr/share/code/resources/app/resources/linux/code.png
```

is incorrect. If the `.desktop` file needs the line to represent the window, it should be:

```
StartupWMClass=code
```

If you fix these two issues, all should work fine :)