# Dock icon differs from desktop file icon

Tags: icons, launcher, .desktop, dock

I created a `.desktop` file per coding environment I have set in VSCode (PHP, Node, C, ...) and I changed the icon in order to have a visual clue of with windows are opened in the dock, but if the icon change works well when I look for the `.desktop` entry in the launcher, It stays the same in the dock (and groups).

I've seen a lot of issues similar to this one, but none of the answers worked for me so far...

I'm using **Ubuntu 20.04** and this is an example of one of my `.desktop` files:

```ini
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=VSCode Vue
Icon=/home/me/icons/vue.png
Exec=vscode_profile vue "%f"

Categories=Utility;TextEditor;Development;IDE;
MimeType=text/plain;inode/directory;application/x-code-workspace;
StartupWMClass=code
```

(my `vscode_profile` simply launch vscode with custom path for `--extensions-dir` and `--user-data-dir`)

[image: .desktop file icons works in launcher]

*.desktop file icons works in launcher*

[image: Dock icons stays the same and group]

*Dock icons stays the same and group*

Some of the other posts that adresse a similar issue but didn't solved mine:

- [18.04 custom icon from .desktop file not populating in dock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081505/18-04-custom-icon-from-desktop-file-not-populating-in-dock)
- [Show desktop icon in Ubuntu 17.10 dock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988063/show-desktop-icon-in-ubuntu-17-10-dock)
- [Synchronise icons between .desktop and dock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245812/synchronise-icons-between-desktop-and-dock)
- [What does the StartupWMClass field of a .desktop file represent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367396/what-does-the-startupwmclass-field-of-a-desktop-file-represent)
- [Icon in Unity launcher (14.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/792745/icon-in-unity-launcher-14-04)
- [What does the StartupWMClass field of a .desktop file represent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367396/what-does-the-startupwmclass-field-of-a-desktop-file-represent?noredirect=1&lq=1)